# How to use one variable for different methods?

Tags: android, variables, methods

I've got a problem with using variable i in methods setViewValue and setOnItemClickListener.
So I need to check value of row in table and then add it to another class.
But for this checking I need to use i in both methods or do it another way.

Can you helpm me with it?

```
String[] from = new String[] {  DB.COLUMN_MON, DB.COLUMN_YEAR };
int[] to = new int[] { R.id.textMonth, R.id.textYear };

scAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.list_item, cursor, from, to);

scAdapter.setViewBinder(new SimpleCursorAdapter.ViewBinder() {
    public boolean setViewValue(View view, Cursor cursor, int columnIndex) {
        for (int i=0; i < 98; i++){
            if (cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DB.COLUMN_MON)).equals(dataMonths[0]) && cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DB.COLUMN_YEAR)).equals(dataYears[i])){
                list.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
                    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                        Intent intent = new Intent(Main_month.this, month.class);
                        intent.putExtra("year", dataYears[i]);
                        intent.putExtra("month", dataMonths[0]);
                        startActivity(intent);
                        finish();
                    }
                });
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
});
list.setAdapter(scAdapter);
```

THANK YOU FOR HELP!
I solve my problem this way:

```
scAdapter.setViewBinder(new SimpleCursorAdapter.ViewBinder() {

                public boolean setViewValue(View view, final Cursor cursor, int columnIndex) {         
                    list.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
                          public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

                                Intent intent = new Intent(Main_month.this, month.class);
                                      intent.putExtra("year", cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DB.COLUMN_YEAR)));
                                      intent.putExtra("month", cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DB.COLUMN_MON)));
                                      startActivity(intent);
                                      finish();                                             
                          }

                    });                                                                                                 
               return false;
               }
          });
```

Comment: You have some major formatting issues making it hard to read your question.

Comment: I declare a variable i in setViewValue. And I use it there. How can I use this variable in method onItemClick?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are only two ways to use a variable in an `onClick` method as well as in other methods.

1. You can declare the variable in the `onClick` method and pass it as a parameter to the other method you need it in.
2. You can declare a class level variable (outside both methods) that has proper scope to be accessed by both methods.

And if you're going for the second method, you need a far more descriptive variable name than just `i`.

Comment: I realised my problem without using variable i. But this answer is truelly.

Answer (score 0):

I think I see what you are doing. You are adding an item listener to your `ListView`, except you are doing it over and over and over again. Bad. nhgrif basically answered the question at hand. I will answer by telling you to not loop. In its current context, you cannot save `i` without declaring a global variable. Only set the `setOnItemClickListener` once! This is the reason for `position` variable included as a parameter; so you know which view was clicked. Check the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.OnItemClickListener.html). Hopefully that helps clarify it.

Edit: I should probably clarify, do not loop and set every item listener. Set the lister ONCE and then loop if you have to, within the click listener that is.

Comment: So the idea of using 'setOnItemClickListener' once really helped me. The programm works without variable i. Thank you ))